# Flash app to iPhone

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Before converting Flash into iPhone app, I still need to understand some questions.

1) Is the converted app able to read XML code from the website like RSS or custom script?
2) 3rd party API are not allowed to be download but assets like Images, sounds or reading data from MySQL db is allow?
3) Anyone port from Flex 4 yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.  Almost all of the regular Flex and AIR APIs still work.
2) Yes.  You can download assets just not load and run them.
3) You can package a Flex 4 app for iOS but performance and usability may not be great right now.  The engineering team working on fixing that.

More details:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/faq.html#otherdevices

Comment: For more assurance, you mean my converted app can access MySQL database and return data or XML script without violation? I wish there is an easier FAQ as to what can and what not in details.

Comment: A remote MySQL database?  Or remote XML?

Comment: Yes to both.  Just as you always would with Flex.